# Implementing Gmail auth in Flask

Tags: gmail, openid, flask

I'm working towards setting up Gmail authentication in a Flask app. There is [this](http://packages.python.org/Flask-OpenID/) extension of Flask - but I can't find a clear idea as to how I'd go about using it to let people log into the app using their Gmail accounts. Any pointers? Much appreciated!

Comment: Honestly, not much. I played around with the example code provided with Flask-OpenID, but I couldn't figure out how to use it with Gmail. Then I tried combing through Google and SO - nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might give you an idea

https://developers.google.com/gdata/faq#GmailAtomFeed

It says

"Does Gmail have a Data API?
No, but you can use http://gmail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13465 Gmail's Atom feed with AuthSub or OAuth 1 to request read-only access to a user's unread messages. The scope should be set to https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/. An example query would be:

GET https://mail.google.com/mail/feed/atom/"

Comment: This solves it. I don't even need access to their emails - I just want them to authenticate themselves, and this solves it for me. Thanks a ton!